# Не понимаю синтаксис данной операции C++

Tags: c++

Имя_статического_метода() = значение;

Что это может быть? Объясните новичку, я даже не знаю как загуглить это.

Comment: Можно хотя бы пример нормальный привести? Не совсем понятно.

Comment: видимо этот статический метод возвращает ссылку, соответственно затем происходит обычное присваивание

Comment: Чемпионат по экстрасенсорике

Comment: @dbg, сравнение == , а не =

Comment: Для абстрактных методов форма записи `virtual void YourMethod()=0;`

Comment: Забавно, что функционально аналогичное выражение типа `v[2] = 5;` для вектора вопросов не вызывает :)

Answer (score 1):

Метод может возвращать `lvalue`-ссылку, по которой присваивается значение.

[Например](https://ideone.com/jGYSrs):

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct SomeType {
    int value;

    SomeType(int aValue): value(aValue) {}
};

struct AnotherType {

    static SomeType st;

    static void print() { cout << "Value is " << st.value << endl; }

    static SomeType& getRef() { return st; }
};


SomeType AnotherType::st(3);


int main() {

    AnotherType at;
    at.print();

    at.getRef() = 5; // implicit ctor call at.getRef() = SomeType(5);
    at.print();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Также, это может быть возврат объекта с перегруженным оператором присваивания (proxy object).